# Importing multiple Excel files into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to create a SSIS package to import 3 Excel files into a SQL Server table.

I need one table to import files one by one which gets truncated each time next file is getting imported. Also one table to store file details like filename and id.

Finally, the 3rd table should import all 3 Excel files along with filename and id.

I tried for each loop container and getting 1st and 2nd table but not getting the final table.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Finally, the 3rd table should import all 3 Excel files along with filename and id*. Didn't understand it. Please elaborate. How can table import anything?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.